# Google Java Script API showing invalid_request while accessing the Calendar Events

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

All of sudden gapi( java script ) is stopped working in my application. Showing invalid_request" in gapi.loader function. I have checked that my api keys are active.

Comment: Can you show us some of your codes? I can't find documentation regarding 'gapi.loader', have you tried 'gapi.client.load' instead? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript

Comment: Where we have to user the gapi.client.load ?